# Creating keytab for computer account to decrypt packet capture

Tags: active-directory, wireshark, kerberos

We are having an issue with our blackberry server (EWSTest fails at autodiscover lookup) and I am running a packet capture with Wireshark in an attempt to diagnose the issue.  There is a conversation that is encrypted with Kerberos (RC4-HMAC) that I would like to read.

After some research, I found that a keytab is necessary.  I read up on using ktpass to generate the keytab, but I am only able to do so for a user account.  It appears the server (rather than a user) is the ticket-requesting client since the AP-REQ has no username.  I am not sure how to create a keytab for a server since I don't know what to enter for the computer's password. (and am afraid to inadvertently reset the computer's password)

Any recommendations on how to generate a keytab for a computer object without breaking anything? (and no, we have no lab environment)

Comment: From MS site..The local copy of the machine password is stored under:

HKLM\SECURITY\Policy\Secrets\$machine.ACC

We store the current password and the previous password under

 CurrVal & OldVal Keys respectively